# Trying to get value of selected tkinter.radiobutton using .get(), but can't get the selected value

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to use radio buttons in python for the first time and am having trouble getting the value of the selected radio button.
`print(test)` just prints out "lamp".
I already looked through a dozen topics on the same problem but could not find an answer.

`tkinter` imported as `tk`

```
def additionalData(df: DataFrame):
            global dataBox
            dataBox = tk.Tk()
            dataBox.title("Additional data")
            dataBox.geometry("300x375+800+400")
            dataBox.config(bg="lightgray")

            sensorLoc = StringVar(value="lamp")
            lblSensorLoc = tk.Label(dataBox, text="Sensor location:")
            lblSensorLoc.grid(row=3,column=1,pady=25)
            rdSL1 = tk.Radiobutton(dataBox, text="Ankle", variable=sensorLoc, value="Ankle", tristatevalue="x")
            rdSL1.grid(row=3,column=2)
            rdSL2 = tk.Radiobutton(dataBox, text="Foot", variable=sensorLoc, value="Foot", tristatevalue="x")
            rdSL2.grid(row=4,column=2)
            rdSL3 = tk.Radiobutton(dataBox, text="Shank", variable=sensorLoc, value="Shank", tristatevalue="x")
            rdSL3.grid(row=5,column=2, pady=25)

            test = sensorLoc.get()
            btn_save = Button(dataBox, text="SAVE", command=lambda: 
            [   
                print(test)
            ])
            btn_save.grid(row=7,column=2, pady=25)
```

I cut out most of the function to make it easier to read

Comment: @toyotaSupra why can I not use StringVar()? In the official documentation for tkinter StringVar() is a valid option for radio buttons. I know I can get it to work with IntVar()

Comment: You can definitely use `StringVar()` - I'm doing it in a tk app presently

Comment: Change your btn_save button command to `command=lambda: [print(sensorLoc.get())]`

Comment: @Derek that changes nothing. I already have ```test = sensorLoc.get()``` and print ```test```

Comment: `sensorLoc.get()` needs to be *inside* the `lambda` so that it updates when you select new radiobutton. If you need to put 'test' in lambda then define `test = sensorLoc.get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test = sensorLoc.get()` will set test to 'lamp' and that's it!
What you need is to update 'test' dynamically, like this.

```
test = sensorLoc.get
btn_save = tk.Button(dataBox, text="SAVE", command=lambda: [print(test())])
```

Now when button is pressed the current radiobutton value will be returned.

Comment: Before I even asked the question here I did the same thing, but something must've been different since it didn't work then. Now it worked, thanks